Why does a well-educated native speaker tell me this?
I have a friend who is a native speaker of English.
The other day I was trying to make up a conversation for the teaching material of my students.
It was like this:
A: I don’t know which college I should go to.
B: Jack told me that he would visit me after work.
B1 If he comes over tomorrow night, he can give you some helpful advice.
B2 If he comes over tomorrow night, he’ll be able to give you some helpful advice.
He says that I should choose B1 because it uses “can” and it’s not because of the number of words or the conciseness. He says that “can” is much better in this case in the meaning.
I argue that people on the internet keep saying that “can” equals “will be able to”, but he simply says that they are totally different in meanings.
I am so confused. Can anyone explain this to me?

Does this answer your question? Compared with "will be able to", does the modal "can" sound more like suggesting an available option to someone?

They can mean the same thing, in fact. I can't OR won't be able come to your house tomorrow. I'm busy. I can't walk, my leg is broken. I'm unable to walk my leg is broken.

he can give you some helpful advice = he has experience in the matter and is able to advise you
he'll be able to give you some helpful advice = he has experience in the matter and will be able to advise you (when you meet)
The main difference is the future aspect of "he'll be". But I don't think that means that his ability will arise in the future. The futurity relates to the time of the meeting.
P.S.It's not that the future couldn't be used in a situation where the ability will be achieved in the intervening time, but the sentence would need to be supplemented to convey that sense:

He's going to his admissions interview this afternoon, so he'll be able to give you some helpful advice tomorrow evening.


I agree that B1 is more idiomatic.
In some cases in English, the present tense can refer to future events. Although this refers to a future event, “If he comes over” is grammatically in the present tense, so it makes more sense to put “he can give” in the present tense as well.
However, B2 is still a correct sentence, and it is still grammatical and easy to understand.

I asked him. He told me that “can” makes it sound more like making a suggestion that the listener should ask Jack for advice, while “will be able to” sounds like Jack will only gain the ability to provide the advice if he comes over tomorrow.
